# Form submit in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have got two buttons, which both submit a form in asp.net.

I need to know in the function below..What button was clicked..The login or register button. And by that information, I want to trigger the one of the functions in the load event.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddCountries();
    AddAge();

      if (IsPostBack)
      {
          string pwd = LoginPassword.Text;
          string saltAsBase64 = "z3llWdYSA2DY3M4uNSpOQw==";
          string hash = HashPass.GenerateHash(pwd, saltAsBase64);

          if (Page.IsValid)
          {
              LoginUser(hash);
         /// Depending on what the user pressed..I need to trigger the function 
        // above or below
              RegisterUser(hash);
          }



      }
}
```

What if I have this in the button event:

FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(currentUser.UserName, false);

will the redirection happen immediately after the button event? or will it trigger the page load event again, ignoring that redirection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the buttons are server side controls `<asp:button/>` then you can handle the event of the (specific) button:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {....}
```

vs.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {......}
```

Which are raised **after** `Page_Load` see: [ASP.Net Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

If you are using standard HTML `<input type=submit />` and posting back to the same page, then   you can inspect the `Request.Form` collection (*which you can also do with server side controls*).

UPDATE:

- `Page_Load` is **always** raised on postback
- client-side validation will prevent a postback
- if you are using server validation controls, check `Page.IsValid` in the handler before executing something
- Depending on your needs, you can also inspect controls/values in `Page_Load` (checking for `Page.IsPostBack` - the point is you have options...

So if you (instead) wanted to inspect on `Page_Load`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if ((UserEmail.Text == "jchen@contoso.com") &&
         (UserPass.Text == "37Yj*99Ps"))
          {
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage
               (UserEmail.Text, Persist.Checked);
          }
        else
          {
            ......
          }
    }
}
```

*above code taken, and slightly modified, from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy.aspx)*

UPDATE2:

If you are using server validation controls, don't use `Page_Load`. Use the button handler and check for `Page.IsValid`.

Comment: no, I am not using regular post items...Thos button events are only going to be executed if the page is valid right?..see update