# Get Internal Error 500 from ajax when try to access to function in aspx.cs

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have some system to show some products and login page.
In my LoginPage.aspx i have all the controllers of input etc.
Now i have some JavaScript file with this Function to handle with login with AJAX:

```
function CheckSignIn() {
var re = /[0-9]/;
if (!re.test($('#PasswordInput').val())) {
  alert("Password must contains only digits!");
}
else
{
    name = $('#UserNameINPUT').val();
    pass = $('#PasswordInput').val();
    var user = {
        userNamePar: name,
        passPar:pass
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "LoginPage.aspx/CheckLoginCodeBehind1",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST", //use only POST!
        data: JSON.stringify(user),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            alert(formatErrorMessage(jqXHR, exception));
        },
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {
            debugger;
            if (result == "") {
                alert("User Not found");
            } else {
                window.location = "ProductsPage.aspx";
            }
        }
    });
}
```

In the CodeBehind of the page (LoginPage.aspx.cs) i have this method

```
 protected string CheckLoginCodeBehind1(string userNamePar, string passPar)
    {
        string PW_input = PasswordInput.ToString();
        bool isValid = PW_input.All(char.IsDigit);
        temp = GetUsers2(userNamePar, passPar);


        if (isValid)
        {
            if (UserNameinput.ToString() != null)
            {
                if (temp != null)
                {
                    result = "UserOK";
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

So.. my problem is when i try to login i get Intrnal Error 500

```
jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:61405/LoginPage.aspx/CheckLoginCodeBehind1 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

And when I do debugging in the client side it seems like the code pass the AJAX section.
What should I do?
thanks for the help!

*Edit*
**This is the function that i check if the user is in the DataBase:**

```
    public string GetUsers2(string un, string pw)
    {
        Users u1 = null;
        try
        {
            Comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM UsersTB WHERE UserName = @name AND Password = @pass";
            Comm.Connection.Open();
            Comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", un));
            Comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pass", pw));
            //bool flag = false;

            Reader = Comm.ExecuteReader();
            if (Reader.Read())
            {
                u1 = new Users(Reader["UserName"].ToString(), Reader["Password"].ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            Comm.Connection.Close();
        }
        JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return json.Serialize(u1);
    }
```

Comment: A 500 error is coming from your server side code. I'd suggest you place a breakpoint and step through it

Comment: what is "PasswordInput.toString()" supposed to give you? surely you should be using passPar?

Comment: @BugFinder "PasswordInput.toString()" is the password that the user's input. And passPar is the password parameter that i checked if it ok in the DataBase (in GetUsers2 function).

Comment: but you seem to be passing the input and then trying to reference the text box .. why not just use passpar for both

Comment: @BugFinder i changed it and now i use only passPar. still dosent helped alot and i still cant debugging the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```
protected string CheckLoginCodeBehind1(string userNamePar, string passPar)
```

To:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string CheckLoginCodeBehind1(string userNamePar, string passPar)
```

Ajax calls to code behind in webforms needs to be decorated with webmethod attribute.

In your js parameters, you also have a user object that you are passing through as a parameter:

```
var user = {
    userNamePar: name,
    passPar:pass
}

...

data: JSON.stringify(user),
```

Your server method is not expecting this user object as you have defined 2 strings, so I would suggest you don't create the user object and change:

```
data: JSON.stringify(user),
```

To:

```
data: JSON.stringify({"userNamePar": name, "passPar" : pass}),
```

Also you appear to be referencing a control:

```
string PW_input = PasswordInput.ToString();
```

You cannot access aspx controls server side in a webmethod via ajax so far as I am aware. If you need to do this I'd suggest you just use a normal post back request.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I try your suggestion and it still doesnt work and i get an Intertnal Error 500

Comment: Looking at your js, you have created a user object.. "var user", your server method is expecting 2 string parameters. I'll add to my answer

Comment: You are totally right. But i change it to your answer and it still won't work :( *edit* How to do the normal post back request?

Comment: You would need to use a submit button, and post the form back - it is probably best if you look up a tutorial for form submission in asp.net webforms... like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365173/form-submit-in-asp-net